# I want the same functionality of ribbon button on queue entity on the dashboard in crm

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I have one dashboard which contains the queue subgrid. If you go to the Queue entity and select any record,you will see the Release Ribbon button. Is there any way that i can put the same button on dashboard when i select any queue item on dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are using the queue items entity on your dashboard. The dashboard ribbon will change depending on which subgrid you have something selected in. [image]